# How to implement the remember device process in Amazon Cognito in Java?

Tags: java, spring, authentication, amazon-cognito

I'm having trouble implementing the process of remembering devices in Amazon Cognito, so that the next time the user logs in it doesn't ask for the 2FA code.

For this I have implemented the first step of 2 that the Amazon website says:

> Remembering devices is a two-part process:
>
> 1. Confirming a new device. Initiate authentication from the device, and then confirm it with Amazon Cognito to get unique device identifiers.
> 2. Verifying a confirmed device. Initiate authentication from a confirmed device to skip the MFA step on subsequent sign-in attempts.

I am with the first step "Confirming a new device" but it does not work for me. The problem is calculating the "passwordVerifier" value.

According to Amazon these are the steps to follow (section "Call ConfirmDevice"): https://aws.amazon.com/es/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cognito-user-pool-remembered-devices/

I have the following code:

```
String HEX_N =
     "FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFC90FDAA22168C234C4C6628B80DC1CD1"
         + "29024E088A67CC74020BBEA63B139B22514A08798E3404DD"
         + "EF9519B3CD3A431B302B0A6DF25F14374FE1356D6D51C245"
         + "E485B576625E7EC6F44C42E9A637ED6B0BFF5CB6F406B7ED"
         + "EE386BFB5A899FA5AE9F24117C4B1FE649286651ECE45B3D"
         + "C2007CB8A163BF0598DA48361C55D39A69163FA8FD24CF5F"
         + "83655D23DCA3AD961C62F356208552BB9ED529077096966D"
         + "670C354E4ABC9804F1746C08CA18217C32905E462E36CE3B"
         + "E39E772C180E86039B2783A2EC07A28FB5C55DF06F4C52C9"
         + "DE2BCBF6955817183995497CEA956AE515D2261898FA0510"
         + "15728E5A8AAAC42DAD33170D04507A33A85521ABDF1CBA64"
         + "ECFB850458DBEF0A8AEA71575D060C7DB3970F85A6E1E4C7"
         + "ABF5AE8CDB0933D71E8C94E04A25619DCEE3D2261AD2EE6B"
         + "F12FFA06D98A0864D87602733EC86A64521F2B18177B200C"
         + "BBE117577A615D6C770988C0BAD946E208E24FA074E5AB31"
         + "43DB5BFCE0FD108E4B82D120A93AD2CAFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF";
 
BigInteger N = new BigInteger(HEX_N, 16);

BigInteger g = new BigInteger("2", 16);

Random random = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
byte[] randomBytes = new byte[16];
random.nextBytes(randomBytes);
String salt = Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(randomBytes);

randomBytes = new byte[40];
random.nextBytes(randomBytes);
String randomPassword = Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(randomBytes);

String fullPassword = Hashing.sha256().hashString(this.getDeviceGroupKey() + this.getUsername() + ":" + randomPassword, StandardCharsets.UTF_8).toString();

String saltFullPassword = Hashing.sha256().hashString(salt + fullPassword, StandardCharsets.UTF_8).toString();

String passwordVerifier = Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(g.modPow(new BigInteger(saltFullPassword,16), N).toString(16).getBytes());

DeviceSecretVerifierConfigType deviceSecretVerifierConfigType = new DeviceSecretVerifierConfigType();
deviceSecretVerifierConfigType.setSalt(salt);
deviceSecretVerifierConfigType.setPasswordVerifier(passwordVerifier);

ConfirmDeviceRequest confirmDeviceRequest = new ConfirmDeviceRequest();
confirmDeviceRequest.setDeviceKey(this.getDeviceKey());
confirmDeviceRequest.setDeviceName(this.getDeviceName());
confirmDeviceRequest.setAccessToken(this.getToken());
confirmDeviceRequest.setDeviceSecretVerifierConfig(deviceSecretVerifierConfigType);

ConfirmDeviceResult confirmDeviceResult = awsCognitoIdentityProvider.confirmDevice(confirmDeviceRequest);
```

and the execution returns the following error

> "com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidp.model.InvalidParameterException: Found negative value for salt or password verifier."

Although other times it returns another error, it is the following

> "com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidp.model.InvalidParameterException: Invalid device key given."

I tried confirming the device and getting it to register with AWS but not enough.